# Remove or add item from list in scala

Tags: scala

Each time check box clicked appropraite id is passed to check method..

```
  @RequestMapping(value = Array("checkBoxCheck.html"))
      @ResponseBody
      def check(@RequestParam checkBoxId: Long) {
      processing(checkBoxId) 

      }

    def processing(checkBoxId:Long){....}
```

the above code is example of spring scala..
i want to add each id to a list ,if it is  exists already remove it from the list in  processing method

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def processing(id: Long): List[Long] = {
  if(list.contains(id))
    list.filter(_ != id)
  else
    list :+ id
}

val list = List(1,2,3)    

scala> processing(3)
res0: List[Long] = List(1, 2)

scala> processing(4)
res1: List[Long] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: instead of double iteration, rather use `list.partition(x => x!=id)._1`

Comment: thanks Brian
But it is right way to call processing method...here dm is another Long list
dm=processing(checkBoxId)

Comment: Brian at run time id' are not append to list it just remove the old one and adding new..

Comment: Call with `val list = processing(checkBoxId)`. The list is not appended to. Processing returns an `immutable` list. If you want the list to be reassigned with each call to `processing` use a `mutable` list.

Comment: import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer already did
and i declared list like this ,var list=List[Long](000000)
it is not working..it does not remove and not adding new id.

Comment: mr jatin..
list.partition(x => x!=id)._1
Could you plz explain what is x,id

Comment: Try playing with `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer` and `scala.collection.immutable.List` in the REPL to gain understanding how they work and then how to make them work for your `processing` function.

Answer (score 1):

'pattern match' use case

```
  def processing(list: List[Int] , id: Int): List[Int] = list match {
    case list if list.contains(id) => list filterNot(_ == id)
    case _ => list :+ id
}  
val list = List(1, 2, 3)                        //> list  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
processing(list, 3)                             //> res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
processing(list, 4)                             //> res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: How can i remove a specific item from list??